# Defining properties on function vs on function.prototype

Tags: javascript, lua

**tl;dr** In case you are familiar with how javascript works, skip to the "question" part.

I come from javascript, where we use the prototype chaining to define our "class" methods such as:

```
function MyClass(){
    return this
}
MyClass.prototype.method = function(){
    // do stuff
}
MyClass.directPropFunction = function(){
    // do direct stuff
}

MyClass.method()                    // doesn't work
MyClass.directPropFunction()        // works
new MyClass()                       // instantiates an object from said "class"
new MyClass().method()              // now it works!
new MyClass().directPropFunction()  // however now no longer works.
```

In other words, defining direct properties on function could be considered `static` methods, where as defining properties on the `prototype` can be considered regular methods. All this rides on the fact that we "fake" classes by using functions as constructors for objects which we then access and use their prototype chains to do magic stuff.

One important thing to note is that even the `.method` that is declared on the prototype is not created for each instance of the object. Does LUA have a "proper" way to extend function objects?

### Question:

I have been fiddling around with LUA a bit and have come across this: I got to ask, since I do not know how it works internally, what is the difference and what is the preferred way of doing things? Also, I am not sure if LUA has the whole "faking" classes, but I wouldn't use it anyway probably, so which of the methods shown bellow is the "correct" way to do things?

```
function Foo()
    -- do stuff
end
Foo.method = function()
    -- do stuff
end
Foo.prototype.protoMethod = function()
    -- do stuff
end
```

What I want to achieve is have the following:

```
function doSomething()
    -- does something, duh
    -- return uniqueID
end
doSomething.revert = function(uniqueID)
    -- reverts stuff
end
```

and then I would be able to do both:

```
local a = doSomething()
doSomething.revert(a)
```

so what is the right approach?

Comment: In Lua, you can't index a function value. In Lua, there are no classes, however they can be emulated: this is one of the ways to do so: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses.

Comment: What you mean by "can't index a function value"? I dont necesarily need/want classes, but I do want to do the very last `code segment` i wrote.

Comment: I mean that `func.property` will cause a runtime error, if `type (func) == 'function'`.

Comment: so essentially `func.property = 2` is okay, but `func.property = function` is not okay if I understand you correctly (case A)? or any `func.property` will error as soon as `func` is a function rather then a `{}`

Comment: And on that point, can any of the two be done with `func.prototype.property` ? Both simple values like `2` / `"foo"` as well as `functions` ?

Comment: > any func.property will error as soon as func is a function rather then a {}
Exactly. And there are no prototypes in Lua, although tables and uservalues have metatables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this exercise:

```lua
local function reversible (func)
    local states = {}
    states [func] = states [func] or {}
    return function (...)
        local result = func (...)
        states [func] [result] = {...}
        return result
    end, function (result)
        return unpack (states [func] [result])
    end
end

local square, root = reversible (function (a)
    return a ^ 2
end)

local initial = -2
local squared = square (initial)
local reversed = root (squared)

io.write ('initial = ' .. tostring (initial) .. ', squared = ' .. tostring (squared) .. ', reversed = ' .. tostring (reversed) .. '\n')
```

Of course, in this example, the "state" that is restored consists of only function arguments; so that `func` has to be pure. It is assumed that the original function returns only obe value (if more, `states` should be indexed with hashes of `func` results packed into a table).

Unlike JavaScript, in Lua functions do not have properties, and objects have no prototypes. However, Lua tables have *metatables*.

Also, function properties can be emulated by table fields, if the table's metatable has a field `__call`, which is used when a table is called like a function. The example below imprements the pseudo-property `revert` and also allows multiple returns for the original finction:

```lua
local function hash (array)
    return table.concat (array, ',')
end

local function reversible (func)
    local states = {}
    states [func] = states [func] or {}
    local wrapped = {
        revert = function (...)
            return unpack (states [func] [hash {...}])
        end
    }
    setmetatable (wrapped, {
        __call = function (tbl, ...)
            local results = {func (...)}
            states [func] [hash (results)] = {...}
            return unpack (results)
        end
    })
    return wrapped
end

local square = reversible (function (a)
    return a ^ 2
end)

print ('square (-2)', square (-2))
print ('square.revert (4)', square.revert (4))
```

Comment: Okay so this is great, but, totally due to my fault, missed the point entirely :P Let me try to give a REAL example of what I need. I am trying to make a `get/release` for an integer array that stores IDs, so the whole `doSomething` / `reverse` was in fact `return i` and then on `reverse` i'd restore i to an array for recycling.

Comment: You mean that an ID that is `got` is stored so that it will never be `got` again until it is `released`, so that effectively `get` moves an `ID` from `spareIDs` array to `usedIDs`, and `restore` moves it back, but you want to implement it on a more abstract level?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I like to learn stuff on the abstract level so that i can understand it better. Currently I am using `id` like an `integer` so the whole storing can be a simple `id++` for the IDs that were handed out and a single array to keep the `released` ones for other calls, but I'd like to write it on an abstract level which is why I used the examples of `any function` rather than specifics. Can you please also answer the comment in the OP i asked, trying to learn :P Thanks

Comment: I think I can implement an abstraction that you have in mind, and it will not differ much from the one in my answer. However, this is not the abstraction that fits your specific task. When you release an ID, you don't want to also release all ID that were issued later, do you? But this rollback is what this "revert" paradigm requires.

Comment: Yeh no, i do not want to rollback everything, i just want that ONE `id` to be released. Maybe my inital example is not that well though out :S

Comment: I will mark your answer as "accepted" because it answers the original post exactly as it should be. I would ask you to also include your explenations as to how indexing doesnt work on functions in the answer from the comments to make it feel "complete". Thanks for assistance

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explenation. Quite a lot is unclear to me, but this is simply coz im not familiar with the language enough, the explenation is clear though. Time to google metatables a bit i guess :D